# USRP B200 mini Transmitter trouble

Tags: c++, usrp, uhd

I have trouble when using my USRP b200 mini. Indeed, I wasn’t able to use it in transmitter mode. I work with two b100 and one b200.
Until now, if I use one USRP b100 in transmitter mode and another one in receiver mode, everything works. If I use one USRP b100 in transmitter mode and my USRP b200 in receiver mode everything still works. But if I do the opposite, I am not able to detect my transmitted signal anymore.
Can someone could help me please ?
I use these C++ code lines to parameter my USRP:

```
void Radio_Tx_Rx::initialize(int TX){
printf("%s",KYEL);
if (TX){
  cout << "TRANSMITTER INITIALISATION " << endl;
    string usrp_addr("type=b200");
    usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(usrp_addr); 
    usrp->set_tx_rate(fe);                        
    usrp->set_tx_freq(fc);                         
    usrp->set_tx_gain(20); //I tested gain from 0 to 80 with a step of 10
    usrp->set_tx_antenna("TX/RX");
    uhd::stream_args_t
            stream_args("fc32");        
    tx_stream = usrp->get_tx_stream(stream_args); 
    cout << " " << string(50, '-') << endl;
    usrp->issue_stream_cmd(uhd::stream_cmd_t::STREAM_MODE_START_CONTINUOUS);
} else {
   cout << " RECEIVER INITIALISATION "<< endl;
    string usrp_addr("type=b100"); 
    usrp = uhd::usrp::multi_usrp::make(usrp_addr); 
    usrp->set_rx_rate(fe);                         
    usrp->set_rx_freq(fc); 
    usrp->set_rx_antenna("TX/RX");
    uhd::stream_args_t
            stream_args("fc32");        
    rx_stream = usrp->get_rx_stream(stream_args); 
    cout << " " << string(50, '-') << endl;
    usrp->issue_stream_cmd(uhd::stream_cmd_t::STREAM_MODE_START_CONTINUOUS);
printf("%s", KNRM);
```

}

Comment: Well, there's a pretty nasty missing `"` in your code, so I'd be very surprised if this compiles at all.

Comment: your title says B200, your text says B100, I think you mean B200?

Comment: @3Dave, Sorry I made a mistake when I uploaded it yesterday. There is not this mistake in my code.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use both of them. I have two B100 and one B200. However my issue is when I use B200 in transmitter. :/